# Bootstrap form does not send file name

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have wrote a form in bannervipsites.php :

```
<form role="form" action="index.php" method ="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>نام بنر :</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="sname" placeholder="نام فارسی یا لاتین بنر">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>URL : </label>
      <input class="form-control" name="surl" placeholder="http://">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Upload banner :</label>
      <input type="file" name='upfile' id='upfile' class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-primary" data-buttonBefore="true" data-icon="false" >
      <input type='hidden' name='bform' value='file'>
      <input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='100720'>
   </div>
   <?php
      if ($acctype != 1) {
      ?>
   <div class="form-group">                                             
      <label>حداکثر بازدید در ساعت : (عدد 0 یعنی نامحدود)</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="scph" placeholder="سقف بازدید در ساعت از چه عددی  فراتر نرود؟">
   </div>
   <?php
      }
      ?>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>روی مربع کلیک کنید : </label>
      <div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="fform" value="bannervip">
   <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="0">
   <input id="submit" name="submit" value="اضافه کردن" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">بستن</button>
</form>
```

and then post it to index.php
but upfile (the name of uploaded file) does not send.
I can not get

```
echo $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];
```

in index.php
what is the problem? it's very odd for me.
it was working in last template .(index.php is ok i'm sure)
what is wrong with bootstrap form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
enctype= "multipart/form-data"
```

to your form.